# Can any continues differentiated h(x,y) function be represented by f1(x)*g1(y) + f2(x)*g2(y)?

Tags: functions, continuity

I'm trying to prove mathematically if this is correct or incorrect.
(Sorry for lack of an accurate tag - I don't know what is the correct one for this question)

Given a continues differentiated 2d function $$h(x,y)$$
then there must be four 1d differentiated functions:
$$f1(x),\ f2(x),\ g1(x),\ g2(x) $$
that fulfill:

$$h(x,y) = f1(x)\cdot g1(y) + f2(x)\cdot g2(y)$$

Note: it is easy to show that not all h(x,y) can be represented by only f(x)*g(y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the function

$$h(x,y)= x\cdot y + x^2 \cdot y^2 + x^3\cdot y^3 $$

You can also expand this example to see that using more than $2$ pairs of functions $f_i$, $g_i$ doesn't help in general.

Comment: You should be able to prove that this function cannot be written in the stated format. Without that proof this answer is of no use.

Comment: @geetha290krm I agree that this is not a full answer but just a hint. OP wrote that it is easy for them to prove the version with just one pair of functions so I thought this hint might suffice for them.